# How to add debugger (binding.pry) in dependecy gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I would like to add `binding.pry` to check some things on fly in kaminari gem which is dependency of activeadmin gem. I use also kaminari as completely separate gem.

```
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre5)
      arbre (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      bourbon
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (~> 1.6)
      jquery-rails
      jquery-ui-rails
      kaminari (~> 0.16.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
      ransack (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails
      sprockets (< 4.1)
```

I've already tried something like below in Gemfile:

```
gem 'kaminari', git: 'https://github.com/hubertjakubiak/kaminari.git', branch: 'v0.16.3'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No need for forking here. You can edit locally installed gems. Just do this:

```
bundle open kaminari
```

It will open the corresponding version of kaminari in your `$EDITOR`. There you can insert debug printing, `binding.pry` or whatever you like. Don't forget to restart the app/server.

And don't forget to clean up when you're done. Either by manually undoing your changes or running

```
bundle pristine kaminari
```

Comment: .. and don't forget to remove it afterwards, so you don't get a surprise interruption when using the gem again months later

Comment: @matthewd: yeah, this may have happened to me :)

Comment: `Don't forget to restart the app/server.` - Critical !! NB - Many a time edited gem files, and wondered why nothing was happening.